# NodeJS setInterval not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm making a module named `rooms.js` for my game in `socket.io` and `canvas`, and I've a function to sync with the client the users data as an object, but `setInterval` is not working on my function `Rooms.Listener()`, the client only get the data **4 times** with `setInterval` at **1ms**, but **only one time** with **10ms**.

**Code:**

```
Listener: function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        // send data to client every 1ms
        Rooms.ListUsers();
    }, 1);
},
ListUsers: function() {
    for(var roomID in Rooms.Obj) {
        var room = Rooms.Obj[roomID];
        // send users data to client
        room.users.forEach(function(uid) {
            var socketID = users.getSocketIDbyId(uid);
            var data = Rooms.getUsersInRoomData(roomID);
            fiveSocket.emitClient(socketID, headers.roomUsers, data);
        });
    }
},
getUsersInRoomData: function(roomID) {
    var room = Rooms.Obj[roomID];
    var obj = {};
    room.users.forEach(function(uid) {
        var user = users.Obj[uid];  
        obj[uid] = {
            username: user.username,
            position: user.position,
            figure: user.figure
        };
    });
    return obj;
},
```

Where's the problem? Thanks

Comment: did you debug it somehow? Where `Listener` is called?

Comment: The Listener is called at the end of the module, before module.export

Comment: Most browsers have a minimum of 4ms on setInterval(), yours is set to 1 ms. Set it above the minimum, if for no other reason than to rule it out.

Comment: I've tested 10ms, it's not working

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: However, the problem is detailled, I've said that setInterval is not working, why ? I don't know, that's why I'm asking here

Comment: In what way is it not working? setInterval doesn't just magically stop working without you telling it to or an error occurring, both of which are easily tested for.

Comment: @KevinB the client only get the data 1 time

Comment: Have you confirmed the server is only sending it one time?

Comment: The setup you are using here is... kindof an anti-pattern. The idea of using websockets is that you only send data to the client when there is new data or the client requests it. Sending out the same data, every ms, is a HUGE waste.

Comment: @KevinB I haven't thought that, i will try now

Comment: I have the exact same problem !! Working with socketIO also....please post a solution If you have found one :)

Answer (score 0):

Double check your methods separately. The code itself should work, problem may be inside your inner methods.

```js
var Rooms = {
  Listener: function() {
    setInterval(function() {        
      Rooms.ListUsers();
    }, 1000); // change to 1ms if necessary
  },

  ListUsers : function() {   
    document.body.innerHTML += Date.now() + "<br />";
  }
};

Rooms.Listener();
```

Comment: SetTimeout is working in this case, I've the date in timestamp logged in my console every 1000ms